# Magento 2.2.2 : Redirect not working from plugin

Tags: magento2, redirect, plugin, 404, around-plugin

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\AppInterface">
  <plugin sortOrder="1" name="noroute_redirect" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin\AppInterfacePlugin"/>
</type>
```

**AppInterfacePlugin.php**

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\AppInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

class AppInterfacePlugin
{

    private $state;
    private $redirectFactory;

    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }



    public function aroundLaunch(AppInterface $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if (condition == true) {
            $this->state->setAreaCode('frontend');
            return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('no-route');
            //exit(0);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

- How do I redirect user to 404 page not found page?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code;

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\AppInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

class AppInterfacePlugin
{

    private $state;
    private $redirect;
    private $url; 

    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }



    public function aroundLaunch(AppInterface $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        if (condition == true) {
            $this->state->setAreaCode('frontend');
            $redirectUrl = $this->url->getUrl('no-route/index/index');
            $this->redirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
            //exit(0);
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception - `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException): Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.
Exception #1 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is not set`